# Continuous median in Ruby

Tags: ruby, statistics, heap

I have written a program in Ruby which calculates the median of a streaming set of numbers dynamically. For each number that arrives, the median is calculated for all the numbers that have arrived so far.

The issue I am facing is that the program times out on some inputs, and, most likely, the reason is that I return a variable that is passed to a routine. I need to do this because this variable changes inside the routine and I can't pass by reference in Ruby.

Is there any workaround for this inability to pass by reference? I have seen the code involving "binding" but I found it clumsy. Why does Ruby not have a simple, straightforward pass-by-reference as do C++, C# and Java? I have pasted my code below.

I maintain two heaps max and min. The value in any node in the max (min) heap is at least as large (small) as the value in any node below it. Any arriving number is inserted into the max heap or min heap with the proviso that the difference in the number of nodes in the two heaps does not exceed 1, and that the heap property be preserved for both heaps. With this proviso, the median can be calculated from the root elements in the two heaps.

```
Node=Struct.new(:v,:l,:r)do
end


max=0
min=0

def count(m)
        m==0 ? 0 : 1 + count(m.l) + count(m.r)
end


def delete(d,type)

      if d==0 
          return 0
      end
      if type=="max"
          if d.l==0 && d.r==0
              return 0
          elsif d.l!=0 && d.r!=0
              if  d.l.v > d.r.v 
                  d.v= d.l.v 
                  d.l=delete(d.l,type)
              else
                  d.v= d.r.v
                  d.r= delete(d.r,type)
              end
          elsif d.l == 0
                 d.v= d.r.v
                 d.r=delete(d.r,type)
              else
                 d.v= d.l.v
                 d.l=delete(d.l,type)
              end
     else
          if d.l==0 && d.r==0
              return 0
          elsif d.l!=0 && d.r!=0
              if  d.l.v < d.r.v 
                  d.v= d.l.v 
                  d.l=delete(d.l,type)
              else
                  d.v= d.r.v
                  d.r= delete(d.r,type)
              end
          elsif d.l == 0
                 d.v= d.r.v
                 d.r=delete(d.r,type)
              else
                 d.v= d.l.v
                 d.l=delete(d.l,type)
              end
     end
return d
    end

def insert(v,type,t)

        if t==0
            return t=Node.new(v,0,0)
        end
            if type=="max"
                    if v>t.v 
                    tmp=t.v
                    t.v=v
                                t.l=insert(tmp, type,t.l)
            else
                                t.l=insert(v,type,t.l)
            end
            else
                        if v<t.v 
                    tmp=t.v
                    t.v=v
                                t.l=insert(tmp, type,t.l)
            else
                                t.l=insert(v,type,t.l)
            end
        end        
                return t

end



n=gets.chomp.to_i

n.times do
    v=gets.chomp.to_i
     if (k=count(max)-count(min))==1 
        if v<max.v
            tmp=max.v
            max=delete(max,"max")
            min=insert(tmp,"min",min)
            max=insert(v,"max",max)
        else
                        min=insert(v,"min",min)
        end
        p (max.v+min.v)/2.0
     elsif  k==0
        if max==0 || v<=max.v
                        max=insert(v,"max",max)
            p max.v/1.0
        else
                        min=insert(v,"min",min)
            p min.v/1.0
        end
     else
                if v>min.v
            tmp=min.v
            min=delete(min,"min")
            max=insert(tmp,"max",max)
            min=insert(v,"min",min)
        else
                        max=insert(v,"max",max)
        end
        p (max.v+min.v)/2.0
     end
end
```

Comment: If you don't want to mess with binding, you can instead wrap your variable in an object and pass the object, which will enable pass by reference.  All you need is something really simple like: "Class Wrapper \n attr_accessor :value \n end"

Comment: "Why does Ruby not have a simple, straightforward pass-by-reference as do C++, C# and Java?" – Java doesn't support pass-by-reference *at all*, it is *strictly* pass-by-value, always, no exceptions. (It has, in fact, the *exact same* semantics as Ruby in this regard.) C++ and C♯ support pass-by-reference, but you have to explicitly ask for it; the default is pass-by-value.

Comment: arrays and hashes are by default mutable, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 7):

### Median vs. Mean

`mean` in math is commonly referred to as 'average'. `Median` means 'the number in the middle'.

The mean for (1, 4, 11) would be (1+4+11)/3.0 == 5.3333...
The median for (1, 4, 11) would be [1,4,11][(3/2.0).floor] == 4

Using your code, when I enter `2 2 3` ( take a list of 2 entries. Give me the value for 2 and 3) I get back `2.5`. That's a mean, not a median. I guess there really is no median for 2 and 3, but for the sake of conversation let's say we use the logic above, it'd be 2.

I'm going to assume you want a mean instead of a median, because implementations speak more to intent than technical words.

### Return Value Causing Timeout?

> The issue I am facing is that the program times out on some inputs,
>   and, most likely, the reason is that I return a variable that is
>   passed to a routine. I need to do this because this variable changes
>   inside the routine and I can't pass by reference in Ruby.

It's not clear to me why you think a timeout is caused when you "return a variable that is passed to a routine." I'm pretty sure that is not the reason.

### Passing by Reference doesn't include Immutables

> Is there any workaround for this inability to pass by reference? I
>   have seen the code involving "binding" but I found it clumsy. Why does
>   Ruby not have a simple, straightforward pass-by-reference as do C++,
>   C# and Java?

Ruby uses pass-by-reference. However, if you "throw away" the referenced object, it will appear that Ruby used pass-by-value. Immutable items like numbers, symbols, strings, etc will always act this way because if they are changed, their reference will always be lost. If you increment or reassign a number, you aren't changing an object. You are point to a different object.

For a trivial example, just drop into IRB:

```
>> x = 8
=> 8
>> x.object_id
=> 17
>> x+=1
=> 9
>> x.object_id
=> 19
```

Without going to far afield of your question, this is because when you change from 8 to 9, you aren't changing the internal state of some object. You're actually pointing to a new object. And if you replaced a mutable object reference in ruby, you'd lose that reference, too.

```
 def change_number(num)
   num = num + 1
 end

 def change_object(obj)
   obj = {}
 end

 def add_to_object(obj)
   obj[:bar] = :baz
 end

>> score = 8

>> score.object_id
=> 17

>> out = change_number(score)
=> 9

>> out.object_id
=> 19

>> score.object_id
=> 17  # number 9 is object 19. A new object.

>> mutable = {fu: 'bar'}
=> {:fu=>"bar"}

>> mutable.object_id
=> 6553100

>> out = change_object(mutable) # this is pass-by-reference
=> {}

>> mutable.object_id
=> 6553100 # same object we passed in

>> out.object_id
=> 7488280 # a new object was created, despite pass-by-reference.

>> out = add_to_object(mutable)
=> :baz

>> mutable.object_id
=> 6553100 # same object

>> mutable
=> {:fu=>"bar", :bar=>:baz}  # object was passed by reference!
```

### Mean Value

This is Code Review. If this were posted on Stack Overflow, I would say, "Don't do it that way. Just keep a single sorted list of the values you've seen. Then use the sum and count."

But since this is a code review site, I'll give you some thoughts on your code.

- Where are your unit tests?
- I highly recommend using full variable names instead of v, k, m, d, etc. We live in a time where computers have more than enough memory to remember an entire word. And there's typically autocomplete. So just type out the full word so when you go back 3 months later you won't have to figure out what each letter meant.
- This is an object-oriented language, so using classes would be helpful. For instance, let's create a NumberList class.

### Refactor using OO

(I'm assuming that `insert(v,"max",max)` should be `insert(value,"max",max)`)

```
Node=Struct.new(:v,:l,:r)do
end

class NumberList
  def initialize()
    @max = 0
    @min = 0
  end

  def count(m)
    m==0 ? 0 : 1 + count(m.l) + count(m.r)
  end


  def delete(d,type)
    if d==0
      return 0
    end
    if type=="max"
      if d.l==0 && d.r==0
        return 0
      elsif d.l!=0 && d.r!=0
        if  d.l.v > d.r.v
          d.v= d.l.v
          d.l=delete(d.l,type)
        else
          d.v= d.r.v
          d.r= delete(d.r,type)
        end
      elsif d.l == 0
        d.v= d.r.v
        d.r=delete(d.r,type)
      else
        d.v= d.l.v
        d.l=delete(d.l,type)
      end
    else
      if d.l==0 && d.r==0
        return 0
      elsif d.l!=0 && d.r!=0
        if  d.l.v < d.r.v
            d.v= d.l.v
            d.l=delete(d.l,type)
        else
            d.v= d.r.v
            d.r= delete(d.r,type)
        end
      elsif d.l == 0
        d.v= d.r.v
        d.r=delete(d.r,type)
      else
        d.v= d.l.v
        d.l=delete(d.l,type)
      end
    end

    return d
  end

  def insert(v,type,t)
    if t==0
      return t=Node.new(v,0,0)
    end
      if type=="max"
        if v>t.v
        tmp=t.v
        t.v=v
        t.l=insert(tmp, type,t.l)
      else
        t.l=insert(v,type,t.l)
      end
    else
      if v<t.v
        tmp=t.v
        t.v=v
        t.l=insert(tmp, type,t.l)
      else
        t.l=insert(v,type,t.l)
      end
    end

    return t
  end

  def add_value( value )
    if (k=count(@max)-count(@min))==1
      if value<@max.v
        tmp=@max.v
        @max=delete(@max,"max")
        @min=insert(tmp,"min",@min)
        @max=insert(value,"max",@max)
      else
        @min=insert(value,"min",@min)
      end

      p (@max.v+@min.v)/2.0
    elsif  k==0
      if @max==0 || value<=@max.v
        @max=insert(value,"max",@max)
        p @max.v/1.0
      else
        @min=insert(value,"min",@min)
        p @min.v/1.0
      end
    else
      if value>@min.v
        tmp=@min.v
        @min=delete(@min,"min")
        @max=insert(tmp,"max",@max)
        @min=insert(value,"min",@min)
     else
       @max=insert(value,"max",@max)
     end

     p (@max.v+@min.v)/2.0
    end
  end
end

keeper = NumberList.new

n=gets.chomp.to_i

n.times do
  keeper.add_value( gets.chomp.to_i )
end
```

Now that we have it in an object, I could write some tests. But since you posted this 3 months ago, I'm not sure you're even going to read it.

### Other things you should change

- This is more complicated than necessary. Think harder about your problem rather than jumping in!
- Ruby has loose typing, so it is possible to put either a number or an object in a variable. But if you're going to do that, your code shouldn't have to know about it. The object should have basically the same interface as a number. In this case, you initialize with an integer 0 and then later use a Node, which response to v, l and r. Not at all the same. I'm a little confused about how this works but I'd think an empty Node would be your best choice.
- Your methods are hard to read. Method names should be "executable comments" ... in other words, you should know on a granular level what's happening just by reading the method name. And they should be written with the idea that a stranger should understand them.
- Use more, shorter methods

### Getting the Mean, the Ruby Way

Finally, here's how I'd implement a mean value in Ruby. Since Ruby allows you to add methods to core classes like Array, it makes some sense to add `mean` and `sum` to those classes. Of course, this will break if you try to do `['Jim', 'Spock', 'McCoy'].sum`. So don't do that.

```
require 'bigdecimal'

class Array
  def sum
    self.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }
  end

  def mean
    BigDecimal.new(self.sum) / self.count
  end
end
```

in the console, you'd do this:

```
>> [2,4,66,32,3].mean.to_f
=> 21.4
```

Comment: Nice answer, instead of adding directly in the `Array` class, you could use refinements https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html  ( I just learned from it from WayneConrad see : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35152333#35152333)

Answer (score 5):

[MustModify did a great review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/152889/14370) of your code as a whole. I won't retread all that but rather look at the overall cleanliness and style of the code.

- Your indentation is all over the place, making it really hard to read at times. Ruby convention is to use 2 spaces of indentation. Spaces; not tabs.
- You could do with more horizontal whitespace, again for readability. I.e. `x = 2` not `x=2`, and `x == foo` not `x==foo`. The whitespace you do have is also all over the place.
- `return` is implicit at a method's exit point. You only need explicit `return`s if you're returning early. And for early returns you have post-fixed contionals, such as `return 0 if d.zero?` (notice also the use of `#zero?` instead of `== 0`, but read on why you shouldn't do that either)
- Don't use zero as a NULL value. Ruby has `nil` and the `Object#nil?` check method. `nil` is also false'y, so in many cases you can skip the explicit `nil?` check. So your `min` and `max` variables should be initialized to `nil` - not integer zero.
- Don't use "magic" strings when you have `Symbol`s. I.e. `"max"` and `"min"` should rather be `:max` and `:min`
- Don't do assignments in conditions (e.g. `if (x = foo()) == bar`; there's really no reason to, and it makes it harder to follow what's happening. Compact code ≠ faster code.
- Don't abbreviate variables (yes, I'm referring to the `Node` ivars in particular). Again, hard to read and follow. Just call 'em `left`, `right`, and `value`.
- Don't specify an empty block for `Struct.new` - it's optional, so leave it out.

And finally, you just have *a lot* of duplication. For instance, `insert` does the same thing in both its main branches apart for one byte: `>` vs `<`. And the story's the same for `#delete`: The only difference between the main branches is `>` vs `<` - the rest of the code is identical and pure duplication.

Really basic refactoring of `#insert` might be:

```
def insert(value, type, node = nil)
  return Node.new(value) if node.nil? # struct ivars are auto-initialized to nil

  # could also say:
  # return Node.new(value) unless node

  if (type == :max && value > node.value) || (type == :min && value < node.value)
    tmp = node.value
    node.value = value
    node.left = insert(tmp, type, node.left)
  else
    node.left = insert(value, type, node.left)
  end

  node
end
```

---

Since the count is given as the first number, another way to calculate the mean (not the median) without storing the entire input would be:

```
mean = 0
count = gets.chomp.to_i

count.times do
  mean += gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts mean.fdiv(count)
```

Comment: All good thoughts. I got so bogged down in the forest I forgot the trees.